# Gravitational lensing experimental data

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-lensing

Is there any experimental data for the gravitational lensing equation

$$
\alpha=\frac{4M}{b}
$$

where $b$ is the distance of closest approach, $M$ is the mass of the object.

I tried Google but didn't find anything.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that equation comes right from the general relativity predictions for how light bends near a massive object. It wasn't pulled from experiments. Are you looking for experimental evidence that confirms the GR lensing predictions?

Comment: I want experimental data for gravitational lensing equation, so I can compare the actual experimental data with general relativity data and check the accuracy. thanks.

Comment: There are a number of observation using the sun as $M$ during eclipses, and you could compare the overall MACHO data set with some assumptions about the distribution of impact parameters and angular velocities (I doubt thee is much statistical significance in a single MACHO event, but there are a *lot* of them).

Comment: Could you please point me to these observations, thank you for help.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tests_of_general_relativity#Gravitational_lensing) has a section on this with some references that might be useful. For example [this paper](http://iopscience.iop.org/0004-637X/699/2/1395/)

Comment: Unfortunately, non of these refs provide clear experimental data for the formula above.

Comment: You don't find much raw (or even processed data) on the open web. Even experiments which have a mandate to make the work public (like the Sloan Digital Sky Survey) require you to dig around a little bit to find out how the data you want is labeled. And that is not a problem: the amount of work involved in getting the data (even if you have to email a colleague and ask for it) is *tiny* compared to the work involved in analyzing it. People here have told you what to look for, and that is all I would expect of a colleague.